# Generating Python Code from user clicks in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

Is there any way to auto-generate Python code in QGIS meanwhile I do clicks, so at the end I can copy/edit it the way I want?

Comment: As long as I work in QGIS I have never met a tool like this, perhaps there is a possibility to integrate a third-party software into QGIS but this is out of my scope. I will probably consider creating a model and then saving it as a python script, can it be your option?